# Accessing value type global variable from a destructor in C#

Tags: c#

Is it safe to (or can we) access any globally declared value type variable inside the destructor of a C# class ?

Thank you

```
public class User
{


    int _internalUserAccountNumber;

    public User()
    {
        _internalUserAccountNumber = InternalUtil.GenerateNewId();
    }

    /*
    *  some methods...
    *
    */

    ~User()
    {
        //For some reason I want to make use of the _internalUserAccountNumber variable; 
        //say print out the value before the destruction of the object for example (or could be in a logging issue)
        Debug.WriteLine("Internal Id : {0}.", _internalUserAccountNumber);
    }

}
```

Inside the [destructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66x5fx1b.aspx) this is what I am trying to do. Is it safe ?

Comment: Please shows us what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Globally as in `static`?

Comment: Globally declared value type in C#? Destructor in C#? Maybe you should post an example as your terminology isn't quite clear.

Comment: public or private member variables

Comment: Provide your relevant code and explain what do you mean by **safe** exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can access them from a finalizer (I think this is what you mean by destructor). However you need to make sure that any reference types were not cleaned up earlier, or you will end up with some nasty exceptions.

Other than to actually perform cleanup, I don't think a finalizer should normally need to access member variables.